# Overflowed with some Row of raisedbuton in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I only try to create circular button for each days of the week. For this I used Raisedbutton and CircleBorder shape, but when I have more than 4 raisedbutton, I have an overflowed, as if there was a padding hidden in the raisedbutton...

```
 new Row (

        children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
                  hoverElevation:5,
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child:   Text(("Lu"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 15.0)),
                  onPressed: ()
                  {

                  },
                  shape: new CircleBorder(
                  )
              ),

 RaisedButton(),

 RaisedButton(),

 RaisedButton(),

 RaisedButton....
]
)
```

Comment: or try to add this property to the buttons: `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`

Comment: @ anmol.majhail I prefer display only one line,  @Zvi Karp no effect ..

Answer (score 1):

For one line you can use SingleChildScrollView widget for scrolling

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                  hoverElevation: 5,
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(("Lu"),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 15.0)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  shape: new CircleBorder()),
              RaisedButton(
                  hoverElevation: 5,
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(("Lu"),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 15.0)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  shape: new CircleBorder()),
              RaisedButton(),
              RaisedButton(),
              RaisedButton(),
              RaisedButton(),
            ]),
          )
```

or You just have to use Wrap widget for multi line

```
Wrap(
              spacing: 2.0, // gap between adjacent chips
              runSpacing: 2.0, // gap between lines
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                    hoverElevation: 5,
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(("Lu"),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 15.0)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: new CircleBorder()),
                RaisedButton(
                    hoverElevation: 5,
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(("Lu"),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 15.0)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: new CircleBorder()),
                RaisedButton(
                    hoverElevation: 5,
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(("Lu"),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 15.0)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: new CircleBorder()),
                RaisedButton(),
                RaisedButton(),
                RaisedButton(),
                RaisedButton(),
              ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

I can custom the padding with this solution

```
new Row (
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[


          Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              shadowColor: Colors.white,

              child: InkWell
                (
                  onTap:() { setState(() {
                    change=1;
                    swiper1();                             }
                  );
               },

                  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child : Text(("Lu"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 15.0)),
    )
              )
          ),


          Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              shadowColor: Colors.white,

              child: InkWell
                (
                  onTap:() { setState(() {
                    change=2;
                    swiper1();                             }
                  );
                  },

                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child : Text(("Ma"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 15.0)),
                  )
              )
          ),
```

....